# Performant way to real-time aggregate the same data multiple times in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I generate reports based on (likely big) Collections in my Meteor application, ideally they would be real time. The reports are annual, but have a monthly listing. I know that there are ways to use MongoDB's aggregate with e.g. [the zvictor:mongodb-server-aggregation package](https://github.com/zvictor/meteor-mongo-server).

Is there a more performant way, such as to avoid thirteen (12 months + year) aggregations?

Comment: Can you generate and store them incrementally? e.g. Store monthly reports in a way that you only need to look at 12 documents to create an annual report?